# When in the Wordpress admin panel, the pages and posts' contents appear but they give a 404 error when viewed in the front end

Tags: wordpress, view, http-status-code-404

The home page appears as well and I can view the excerpts of the pages and posts from the home page, but whenever I click on any of the page or post links, or click on 'view page' or 'view post' button in the admin panel, the page returns with a 404 error.

I made sure database was correctly connected, what could possibly be the error?

Comment: Did you try to save the permalinks again? If not, go to the admin panel and then to Settings/Permalinks and click _Save Changes_. This will rebuild your permalinks and maybe that's all you have to do :)

Comment: It is 70 percent caused by your permalink parameters as Sven said. I already faced such issue. Anyway, it is better if you tell us what is your permalink setting, and if you are using custom permalink structure, edit your post giving us the structure. Also indicate whataver you are using custom post types or only default post type.

Comment: I tried saving again on the permalinks page but didn't work. I'm using custom page and post items from Elegant Themes wordpress themes.

Comment: At the bottom of the permalinks page, it gives the .htaccess error where it reports it couldn't create/edit the .htaccess file and gives the code that should be in the .htaccess file. Could this cause the whole problem?

Comment: Yes, that is most likely the problem. You'll have to either create or edit the .htaccess file and include the content it gives you in the error.